# Right and wrong answers and 'opinions'

Tags: discussion

I recently read through this question:

[Why is there no rise of extreme-left in present-day Europe?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/why-is-there-no-rise-of-extreme-left-in-present-day-europe)

And it struck me that there could be multiple answers to this question [point #1] and those answers may not be based on hard cold facts but could be *opinion* based [point #2].

**Point #1**

Being more used the *standard* programming stack exchange and movies and sci-fi I'm used to the fact that generally there is **one** definitive answer to a question. However, with politics (and especially the question I highlighted above) there may be more than one answer to the question which, when combined would give a definative answer.

**Point #2**

Again, with reference to the above question, I suspect that there's no definative answer (with references) that can be given. We therefore fall to the opinion and perception of the respondant.

So...

On Poltics SE are opinion based answers that cannot be backed up with published information acceptable ?

And...

If one answer has been given (even if accepted), can *more* answers then be given ?

Comment: only "one" definitive answer for anything but the most trivial of programming questions?  are you mad?

Comment: You should hang out on \[tag:perl\] tag more often :)

Answer (score 1):

So long as an answer actually attempts to answer the question, and doesn't contain profanities, it will not be *deleted.*

If there's a problem with the answer's quality, or if you aren't satisfied with it's completeness or accuracy, then those are handled by upvotes and downvotes.

---

People are allowed to vote either way for almost any reason that they see fit.

The criteria that I personally use is actually incredibly subjective.  I try to put myself in the shoes of someone who is asking the question, and I try to determine whether I'm convinced that the answer is correct, and I try to determine whether or not it actually fulfills the curiosity I was asking about.  If both are true, I upvote.  If one of them is not true, I down-vote.  Sometimes, I'm not sure, so I don't vote.

---

As a note, opinion-based questions(questions that can't be answered with anything but opinions), will usually get closed.  That question you linked is on the precipice of being too opinion-based, so I wouldn't take that as the model question for this site.